# Severless Function using Lambda AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm trying to follow the url given below.

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/

I've successfully completed all the steps. But when I try to Invoke Request Unicorn. I'm getting the below error in console.

> Failed to load
>   https://jvhlk3ly43.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/ride:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin
>   'http://wildrydes-naveen-muralidharan.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'
>   is therefore not allowed access. ride.js:34 Error requesting ride: 
>   error , Details:   ajaxError @ ride.js:34 fire @ jquery-3.1.0.js:3243
>   fireWith @ jquery-3.1.0.js:3373 done @ jquery-3.1.0.js:9100
>   (anonymous) @ jquery-3.1.0.js:9332 error (async) send @
>   jquery-3.1.0.js:9360 ajax @ jquery-3.1.0.js:8999 requestUnicorn @
>   ride.js:19 handleRequestClick @ ride.js:87 dispatch @
>   jquery-3.1.0.js:5110 elemData.handle @ jquery-3.1.0.js:4918 ride.js:35
>   Response:  undefined

Could someone help me to configure the CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is usually done on the API Gateway level, you just need to configure it and deploy the stage

Check: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

[image]

Comment: I've Enabled CORS and staged it. I'm getting the below error in result variable.`"RequestId: 6e17ed4f-bd38-11e8-8e49-ef2daf847d3b Process exited before completing request"`

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the code @NaveenMuralidharan but this means that you've passed the CORS issue and now hitting the code.